# Translate mouse input to gamepad stick

Tags: visual-c++, input, mouse, gamepad

I'm trying to emulate a gamepad thumbstick by converting mouse input but I'm having a lot of trouble making it smooth, all I can get is short jagged movements. Does anyone know how I can smooth this out without creating a noticeable amount of lag? I tried copying some values out of the PCSX2 lilypad plugin without much success.

This code gets the current mouse position, subtracts it from the last mouse position and calculates the force which should be applied to the thumbstick. The force gets applied up to the max and min values for the thumbstick which are 32767 and -32767 respectively.

I think there may be a couple of problems with this code - if I process it constantly without pausing sometimes it thinks the mouse hasn't moved and resets it back to 0 resetting all movement, obviously sleeping so it has more time to read mouse movement causes lag which isn't really an option here. What I need is a way of calculating a smooth amount of force to apply without resetting movement or adding lag to input.

```
POINT cursorPos{ 0, 0 };
POINT cursorPos2{ 0, 0 };
GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
cursorPos2 = cursorPos;

while(true){
    GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
    int dx = cursorPos.x - cursorPos2.x;
    int dy = cursorPos.y - cursorPos2.y;

    if (dx != 0)
    {
        unsigned short rightX = axisInput.RightX;
        int force = (int)((SENSITIVITY*(255 * (__int64)abs(dx))) + BASE_SENSITIVITY);
        if (dx < 0)
        {
            if ((rightX + force) > 32767)
                rightX = 32767;
            else
                rightX += force;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((rightX - force) < -32767)
                rightX = -32767;
            else
                rightX -= force;
        }
        axisInput.RightX = rightX;
    }
    else
        axisInput.RightX = 0;

    if (dy != 0)
    {
        unsigned short rightY = axisInput.RightY;
        int force = (int)((SENSITIVITY*(255 * (__int64)abs(dy))) + BASE_SENSITIVITY);
        if (dy < 0)
        {
            if ((rightY - force) < -32767)
                rightY = -32767;
            else
                rightY -= force;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((rightY + force) > 32767)
                rightY = 32767;
            else
                rightY += force;
        }
        axisInput.RightY = rightY;
    }
    else
        axisInput.RightY = 0;
    ...
    cursorPos2 = cursorPos;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please describe what processing this code does, and be more precise in what you want to achieve related to this code.

Comment: I've updated my question with a bit more detail.